# Page title not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

The page title is not working?
I am new to coding and dont know if I am making any silly mistake

*application_helper.rb*

```
def title(page_title)
  content_for(:title) { page_title }
end
```

*application.html.haml*

```
%title
  The Project. | #{yield :title || ""}
```

*edit.html.haml*

```
%h2.title Edit Project Details
```

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
= title "Edit Project Details"
```

Comment: still its not working the #{yield :title} doesnt seem to be working

Answer (score 0):

A couple things, first it looks like your code is really confused with the spacing and use of the yield method.  The other thing though, you don't actually have to do an || "".  It won't display anything if there is nothing to display.

I have something very similar in my project.  And what I did was use this code

```
%title
  = "#{yield(:title)} | Company Name"
```

As a commenter pointed out, this can be further simplified to:

```
%title
  #{yield(:title)} | Company Name
```

And finally, from the other post, you do need to make sure it says

```
= title("title")
```

somewhere in your code.